# excel vba - sort txt file in shell

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a `.txt` file with 4 lines which contains the following lines:

> 4
>
> 1
>
> 3
>
> 2

I then use "Shell" to sort the file. The result is sorted:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

Finally I am reading the sorted file and write each line into a second file, but they come out at the original order!

Please help.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub my_mac2()
   Dim my_path, my_tmp_file, my_out_file, my_data_from_tmp, my_command As String
   Dim my_tmp_file_num, my_out_file_num As Integer
   my_path = "E:\MASAV\VBA\"
   my_tmp_file = my_path & "_tmp.txt"
   my_out_file = my_path & "_out.txt"
   my_tmp_file_num = FreeFile()
   Open my_tmp_file For Output As #my_tmp_file_num
   Print #my_tmp_file_num, "4"
   Print #my_tmp_file_num, "1"
   Print #my_tmp_file_num, "3"
   Print #my_tmp_file_num, "2"
   Close #my_tmp_file_num
   my_command = "sort " & my_path & "_tmp.txt /O " & my_path & "_tmp.txt"
   Shell my_command, vbHide
   my_tmp_file_num = FreeFile()
   Open my_tmp_file For Input As #my_tmp_file_num
   my_out_file_num = FreeFile()
   Open my_out_file For Output As #my_out_file_num
   While Not EOF(my_tmp_file_num)
       Line Input #my_tmp_file_num, my_data_from_tmp
       Print #my_out_file_num, my_data_from_tmp
   Wend
   Close #my_tmp_file_num
   Close #my_out_file_num
End Sub
```

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, please note that you have not properly declared your variables. Everything is `Variant` except for `my_command` and `my_out_file_num` which are explicitly declared.

Comment: Those were merely typo errors when placing my Q here. My macro has FreeFile() and #my_tmp_file_num. Thanks anyhow.   Still looking for a solution.

Comment: This code is working as expected, for me. Both the `_tmp.txt` file and the `_out.txt` file are sorted in the proper order.

Comment: Works fine for me as well. Try your typo corrected code now.

Comment: On a related note: If you are creating the original TXT file, why don't you simply create it in the desired sequence? Why resort to a Shell command to sort the file if you have control over the input?

Comment: David, the problem is in a very complicated macro i have where i need the 1st file to be sorted and then read into a 2nd file. I recreated the problem in this sample macro. Of course I corrected the typo. Problem persists. How come you get it right and I don't...? I have Excel 2010 on XP pro. Any idea?

Comment: @gadi strangely it works when I use breakpoints or step-trace it. When  I run the entire code it causes the problem. I thought the problem might be because `my_data_from_tmp` is not initialised, but that did not change a thing. Still working on it.

Comment: Oh...! It works for me too when i use the F8 for step-tracing it. Very strange...

Comment: OK!!! SOLVED!!!!! Floris gave me the idea to sort the file not into itself, but rather into another file (tmp2), then read read "tmp2" and write it's lines into my "out" file. Now the "out" file is sorted. But i still wonder why the previous version worked when in debug mode. THANKS everybody. Gadi

Comment: well, nearly solved. The "Shell" sorting creates the tmp2 file, but opening this file fails with an error saying file not found. When step-tracing it - no problem. I guess VBA is too fast and tries to open the file before it is properly closed by the shell command. I'll try pausing the macro for a couple of seconds before opening the file. (now i'm going to check out to pause...). Will you know.

Comment: i added the following after the shell sorting command :      Application.Wait (Now() + CDate("00:00:01"))
which makes it wait for 1 second. Now all is fine and it also answers why it was working before only in the bebug mode. Thanks again. You people are VERY helpful!

Comment: @gadi I had a similar hunch...was just too lazy to try it. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the `sort` command, the command line is generated from

```
my_command = "sort " & my_path & "_tmp.txt /O " & my_path & "_tmp.txt"
```

In other words - you are using the input file as the output file, and I suspect that's not a good idea. Is that what you intended to do?

You did declare two different file names earlier;

```
my_tmp_file = my_path & "_tmp.txt"
my_out_file = my_path & "_out.txt"
```

so why don't your change this line to

```
my_command = "sort " & my_tmp_file & " /O " & my_out_file
```

This produces output in the second file, and makes the subsequent part of the code unnecessary.  If you want the first file to be also sorted, you can copy the second back into the first.

Comment: OK!!!   SOLVED!!!!!  Floris gave me the idea to sort the file not into itself, but rather into another file (tmp2), then read read "tmp2" and write it's lines into my "out" file. Now the "out" file is sorted. But i still wonder why the previous version worked when in debug mode.   THANKS everybody.   Gadi